# When the motor bike tire changes

Tags: tire, replacement

After how many kilometers I use, I have to change it. Because I use the tubeless tire on my bike?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about motor bikes

Comment: You replace the tire when it's worn out, is falling apart, or has been damaged beyond reasonable repair.

Comment: @mohamedjamzith please use the EDIT button if your question is about an ebike, and not a motorbike.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean an e-bike/pedelec with “motor bike” i.e. a bicycle where – in most jurisdictions – the motor is only allowed to support you up to 25km/h and is limited to 250W of power. The tires of such a bicycle are no different from a normal bicycle. Some tires are marked as “e-bike ready” or something like that, but there is no inherent difference. Usually they are just more puncture proof and heavier.

As Daniel already pointed out in the comments, you should replace your tires when they are worn out or damaged.

Regarding normal tread wear: You can safely use tires until the tread is completely worn away and the fabric or puncture protection (usually a different, non-black color) is showing. Worn tires can be more prone to punctures (since there is less rubber). Knobby tires (e.g. on a MTB) are obviously going to suffer from decreased grip when the tread/knobs is worn down.

Some tires have a tread wear indicator. Usually it’s a small dot-shaped depression or a feature in the tread. This allows you to gauge how much tread you have remaining.

The tread can last anywhere from 1000km to 10Mm, it all depends on the rubber mixture, power output, surfaces and how (much) you brake. Soft, knobby tires (e.g. Cyclocross) will usually wear pretty fast on tarmac while touring tires can last a long time.

Cracks in the sidewalls are usually just a cosmetic issue and not a real problem.

In the end it’s the fabric which gives a tire its strength against pressure, not the rubber. As long as the fabric is undamaged it won’t explode or otherwise fail catastrophically.

Edit: Thread corrected to tread.

Comment: Slight edit needed here - when you say "thread" (thread is completely worn away) 
 you men "tread" right?  It is slightly confusing because there are both threads and tread in a tyre carcass.

Comment: Also, since OP's question *might* have been about motor bikes (ie those without pedals) there may be legal minimums for tread depth, just like there are on car tyres.

Comment: Ooops, sorry. Not a native speaker, of course I meant tread, not thread.

Comment: @Criggie I supect it's actually about an e-bike, given the reference to tubeless. (Actual motorbikes are always tubeless, right? If so, one wouldn't mention it.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Motorbikes moved to tubeless on road motorbikes after cars but well before bicycles.  Off-road motorbikes may still be either tubed or tubeless - depends on how deep offroad they go, and for the same reasons as touring/deep country MTB riders.